# How to enable IP and Port in WHM?

Tags: whm

I'm having problems to send Push Notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging, with PHP.

> **Curl Error -**
>   Failed to connect to fcm.googleapis.com port 443: Connection refused

I need to know where I can enable a 443 port and the IPs that FCM uses to send notifications.

And I also need to know if there is a chance that a firewall automatically block the port and IP address. If so, I'd like to know how to disable it.

And I also need to know how to enable all IPs address for port 443.

Comment: Sorry by my english, I'm not fluent.

Comment: There is a possibility a firewall is blocking something. To my knowledge, there are several available potentially for WHM. You may want to look for any installed in your installation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The firewall was blocking the domain **fcm.googleapis.com** that begin with 216.XXX.XXX.XXX.

```
Firewall Deny IPs
216.0.0.0/8
```

I removed that line and it worked!